# sending specific array value to email php

Tags: php, arrays, output

I am using this code to output multiple specific values from array and sending these values to email.

If i write this:

```
print_r( $products[1]['Notes'], true )
```

Then it is displaying 1 value off course I have put "[1]" to just targeting 1 row.

and If i write this:

```
print_r( $products, true )
```

Then it is outputting all the values and all the rows.

Is there anyway i can output just multiple values of "Notes"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your php is 5.5 and more - use [`array_column`](http://php.net/array_column) function:

```
print_r(array_column($products, 'Notes'), true);
```

Otherwise, you need to select required columns with a `foreach` and print'em:

```
$columns = [];
foreach ($products as $prod) {
    $columns[] = $prod['Notes'];
}
print_r($columns, true);
```

Comment: it is displaying the values but with this: "Array ( [0] => product 1 [1] => product 2 )". Is there any way i can just display "product 1, product 2"?

Comment: I achieved that through implode

Answer (score 1):

There's an [`array_column()`](http://php.net/array_column) function that could help you here.

```
<?php
$data = [
    ['Notes' => 'test1'],
    ['Notes' => 'test2'],
    ['Notes' => 'test3'],
    ['Notes' => 'test4'],
    ['Notes' => 'test5'],
    ];

$notes = array_column($data, 'Notes');
print_r($notes);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => test1
    [1] => test2
    [2] => test3
    [3] => test4
    [4] => test5
)
```

https://3v4l.org/Mp24S

Answer (score 1):

```
$notes = array();
$i = 0;
while($i<count($products)){
  $notes[] = $products[$i]['Notes'];
  $i++;
}
print_r($notes);
```